# Json_encode - то в массив, то в объект

Tags: json, php

Всем привет.

Есть такой код

```
foreach($sett as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v["funcsPole"] as $k1=>$v1){
        if($v1=="")unset($v["funcsPole"][$k1]);
    }

    $tmp=json_encode($v);
    $db->Query("UPDATE `fields` SET params='".$tmp."' WHERE id=$k AND zone_id=$zone_id");

}
```

Массыв $sett передается через форму, в нем 6 значений, все абсолютно одинаковые. Но при кодирование его в JSON Получается такой результат:

```
array(6) {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (4) {
    ["numPole"]=>
    string(4) "wera"
    ["namePole"]=>
    string(3) "asd"
    ["funcsPole"]=>
    array(4) { <- тут
      [0]=>
      string(5) "cam_4"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "cam_3"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "cam_4"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "cam_5"
    }
    ["priorPole"]=>
    string(2) "32"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    ["numPole"]=>
    string(3) "wer"
    ["namePole"]=>
    string(4) "werr"
    ["funcsPole"]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) { <- тут
      ["0"]=>
      string(5) "cam_3"
      ["2"]=>
      string(5) "cam_4"
    }
    ["priorPole"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
```

То есть, то что выделено (<- тут), для первого значения массива кодится как массив, а во втором значении как объект. С чем это может быть связано?

Форма имеет 6 разделов, каждый раздел передается как элемент массива

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не подряд элементы массива, хоть и индекс числовой,  видимо, енкодер считает что безопаснее  сделать из него объект. если вам нужно чтобы всегда было одинаково, то используйте JSON_FORCE_OBJECT при
кодировании или true вторым параметром при декодировании

вот этот пример показывает наглядно в чем проблема:

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $arr[]=$i;
}
$j1=json_encode($arr);
unset($arr[3]);
$j2=json_encode($arr);

echo "$j1\n$j2\n-------\n";
print_r(json_decode($j1));
print_r(json_decode($j2));
echo "------\n";
print_r(json_decode($j1,true));
print_r(json_decode($j2,true));
```

http://ideone.com/QVNxUc

Comment: Действительно порядок элементов идут не подряд. Но можно ли в любом случае преобразовать это в массив, а не в объект? то есть как заставить JSON закодировать квадратными скобками,  а не фигурными, не зависимо от порядка индексов?

Просто поле funcsPole (там их 4) может заполнятся не попорядку. Один из них может быть пустым передаваться. На сервере я его исключаю и кодирую.

Answer (score 3):

Объект заключается в фигурные скобки { }. Между именем и значением стоит символ ": ", а пары имя/значение разделяются запятыми.
Массив (одномерный) заключается в квадратные скобки [ ]. Это множество значений, имеющих порядковые номера (индексы) и значения отделяются запятыми.

Это я к чему: может всё-таки есть какие-то различия в оформлении передаваемого массива?
Не плохо было бы взглянуть на исходный вариант $sett, до любых его преобразований...

Answer (score 0):

Как и было сказано другими пользователями, все дело в функции кодирования. JSON предпочитает превращать ассоциативный массив в stdClass. Если хочется заменить обратно на ассоциативные массивы, то следует добавить параметр с константой JSON_FORCE_OBJECT. json_decode($json_str, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);